# Updating security group in another VPC throws error of InvalidPermission.NotFound

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, boto3

so I am working on script that will delete port `22` on `0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0`, now below script is working fine on default vpc but when I change vpc it gives **invalid permission not found error**. I am not able to understand why its giving errrr in another VPC but working fine in default VPC

```
  def update_port(fromport, toport, groupid, vpcid):
            response = client.revoke_security_group_ingress(
                GroupId=groupid,
                IpPermissions=[
                    {
                        'FromPort': fromport,
                        'IpProtocol': 'tcp',
                        'IpRanges': [
                            {
                                'CidrIp': '0.0.0.0/0'
                            },
                        ],
                        'Ipv6Ranges': [
                            {
                                'CidrIpv6': '::/0'
                            },
                        ],

                        'ToPort': toport,

                    'UserIdGroupPairs': [
                        {
                            'GroupId': groupid,

                            'VpcId': vpcid,
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
            )
```

execution:

```
update_port(22,22,'sg-groupid','vpc-vpcid')
```

error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidPermission.NotFound) when calling the RevokeSecurityGroupIngress operation: The specified rule does not exist in this security group.
```

Answer (score 0):

ERROR is self explanatory 
**The specified rule does not exist in this security group.**
Please check if rule is exist or not.

Comment: rule exist if you can read my question properly I stated that function works perfect on default vpc but issue comes in another vpc sg.

Comment: If 4 rules (as shown on the console) are being returned as one rule with multiple IP ranges, how do I remove only the rule for one of the IP ranges? (I took the rule that I fetched and kept only the range for the rule that I want to remove, and then this error still occurs)